# Using gdbserver on remote device w/ a single serial connection?

Tags: linux, debugging, serial-port, gdb, gdbserver

I'm debugging an embedded application that runs in a Linux environment on a remote target. The only usable interface to the board is a single serial interface. Right now that's hooked up /bin/sh on init. I'm connecting with minicom, (re-)loading my application with lrzsz, and using printfs to get the job done.

I'd like to use gdbserver for more fine-grained debugging, but connectivity seems like a problem. Normally I'd connect over ethernet, but that's not available on this hardware. I understand gdbserver can run on a serial line, but right now my one comm port belongs to the shell.

Is there a good way to work around this restriction? Ideally I'd like to be able to run gdbserver and get back to a shell when I'm finished. I've tried starting gdbserver from the shell using the one available serial interface (/dev/ttyS0), then quitting minicom and starting GDB on my host, but it's messy & doesn't appear to work (even after setting remotebaud appropriately). *Should* that work? What's the sane thing to do in this situation?

Answer (score 3):

How about the old-school solution? [Use PPP to run IP networking over your serial line](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/PPP-HOWTO/index.html). You can then ssh (or even telnet) to your board, and connect to gdb at the same time. Given your circumstance, I'd recommend starting `pppd` manually to reduce the risk of locking yourself out through misconfiguration. The LDP link dates from 2000, but contains a lot of debugging advice.